# launch selenium with python on osx

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I have the following script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = "/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
browser.get('0.0.0.0:3500')

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

I get the following error after interrupting the program

```
$ python3 functional_tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 6, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409710 (0c4084804897ac45b5ff65a690ec6583b97225c0),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

I have chrome installed on osx. And I know the path to the chrome binary  in the script is correct. What may be wrong?

Comment: It looks like you need to install the ChromeWebdriver on you mac. http://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/

Comment: chromedriver is installed via homebrew `brew install chromedriver` is on the path as I can execute `chromedriver` from the commandline as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the path to your `chromedriver` binary when you instantiate `webdriver.Chrome()`

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/my/chomedriver', chrome_options=opts)
```

The [official documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) suggests that you "include the path to ChromeDriver when instantiating webdriver.Chrome" *in addition to* including the `chromedriver` location in your `PATH` variable when you are using it in Python.

If you do not know the location of `chromedriver`, you can execute `brew info chromedriver` to see the path in addition to other information.

Comment: no dice. Adding `browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=opts)` gives the same error I reported in the question.

Comment: @HarryMoreno have you tried without providing the path to the chrome binary (i.e., getting rid of the `chrome_options` argument)?

Comment: without providing the path I get `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`

Comment: @HarryMoreno, one last thing to try: set `opts.binary_location` to: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome` I have seen this path referenced in multiple places (note the difference between this and the path you use).

Comment: no chrome at that location. Inspecting `/Applications/` I can see Chrome.app listed there.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas. I have more experience working with these things on Linux. Hopefully someone else will have a solution for you.